# How to make x axis lie on y=0 on Octave gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, octave

How to make x axis lie on y=0? Right now it's lying on whatever is ymin.

Comment: take a look at the documentation of the function `axis`

Comment: @carandraug: are you sure? it's not in `help axis` of Octave version 3.6.1. I found the information in the [Octave manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/octave.pdf) in section 15.3.3.3.

Comment: Nevermind. I misread your question. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add zeroaxis with the `set` command:

```
plot(...)
set(gca, "xaxislocation", "zero")
```

You may also want to add:

```
set(gca, "box", "off")
```

There is a similar discussion on the [octave mailinglist](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/change-position-of-x-axis-td3893956.html).

Answer (score 6):

I do not know if they changed syntax in Octave versions or there is something specific in my code or functions but with Octave version 4.4.1 I was not able to get this axis with "zero" but with "origin"

```
    set (gca, "xaxislocation", "origin")
```